Is there anything wrong with me buying the new home and then moving in 60 days later?
I am in the process of buying a new home. The home I am planning on buying is new and it is just sitting there. I will not be ready to move for several months. The seller wants to
close in about 30 days.
Is there anything wrong with me buying the new home and then moving in 60 days later?
Note: I plan to sell stocks and bonds to pay for the new home.

Is your question about how to structure the financial aspect of buying the home, or about how to take care of the home until you move in?

I'd be happy to go spend a week in it for you some time over the winter. For a very reasonable fee. ;)

Why would it be wrong?  Local by-laws against vacancies?

Do you have someone you trust (even a bit) in the neighbourhood, who could swing by regularly? And could air it out? Is there grass that'll need to be cut or pool to be cleaned/maintained? Is there an alarm?

@spuck I am looking for any issues related to not moving in right away.

Since you are in the US, it's advisable to move in ASAP; otherwise you may find it occupied by someone else when you move. Vacant houses are a target for homeless people, and there are many of them.

@Wastrel Squatting in vacant homes is so rare statistics aren't even collected on it. There's been an explosion of news stories about squatters recently, but not much evidence to show the practice is actually on the rise. Many recent stories about squatters are about delinquent tenants who stopped paying rent, not homeless people randomly moving into an empty house. The chance the OP will find a squatter in their home after 60 days is exceedingly low almost anywhere, no need to fearmonger.

We took ~ 6 months from when we got the keys to when we moved finally in. (It was in Germany, though.)

@NuclearHoagie I'm aware of that. It depends where the home is. In the city where I live, any vacant property in some parts of town is likely to be occupied. The city does nothing. I called 311 a few weeks ago to report people staying in a vacant business downtown. The 311 operator told me to call 911 because they were trespassing. I said 911 was for emergencies, and it's not an emergency until someone is injured or they start a fire. Within a week, the place burned down. I'm not fearmongering, I'm suggesting a possibility.

First and foremost check with your insurance company.  They may not like this, and may deny coverage for a vacant home.
Additionally you will want to visit the property every few days.  A popular thing for thieves to do is steal appliances in vacant homes.  This, primarily, happens with new construction but could also happen in your case.  You also don't want squatters to move in, which has become a problem in several jurisdictions.
Keep in mind this property transaction will be public record, so you want to show some kind of activity at this property.
This is a good time to do any home improvements.  Not living in a home makes it convenient to install things like ceramic tile which cannot be walked on after it is laid.  Also you will not have to move any furniture to do any other kinds of flooring or painting.
This is all assuming that you are able to make the mortgage payment on this place, and the payment on whatever place you are living now.
Edits based on comments:
You should have water and power turned on.  Have the AC set somewhat high, but enough to keep the humidity at bay.
Power outages tend to be short term, and rarely lead to mold.  During Charlie, I lost power for 10 days, in August, and had no mold issues.
Pipes bursting are not really an issue in most of Florida.  (Perhaps some places in the pan handle).
If this was new construction, it may be advisable to install blinds/curtains as without it is easy to see into the house and that it is vacant.  If not new construction, check with the sellers on what will be taken with them.
Most of Florida is not kind to squatters, so you have that going for you.

If there's a primary residence mortgage, the standard (Fannie Mae/Freddie Mac) requirement is occupancy within 60 days (continuing for at least one year), eg https://guide.freddiemac.com/app/guide/section/8405.1

@KelvinSherlock I plan to pay cash for the home.

@Pete B The new home is  in Florida and I am in New Jersey. My current home is mortgage free.

@Bob for the record I am in FL.  So the thievery applies.  My insurance company was a bit cranky about leaving a home vacant when I was in a similar situation, but they were cool since I went by every few days (they were only 6 miles apart).

The insurance and the squatters/thieves are the biggest items that come to mind. What about utilities? Not an issue in Florida, but in my neck of the woods having the power off but the water on during the winter months would be a problem.

@spuck Power failure in Florida's summer is going to cause a mold disaster.

Even a new home may need some work to customise it, depending on how much input the buyer had and how soon (this will of course vary with location builder, etc. etc.).  That also gives you an excuse for not moving in, if you need one, and puts people on site (though that requires a significant level of trust in itself as you won't be present)

Don't forget other maintenance that can advertise no one is living there-- mow the lawn, for example.


The home I am planning on buying is new and it is just sitting there.

New doesn't mean it doesn't have problems. You will want to get a home inspection to reduce the chances of there being problems.
Make sure the insurance company knows it will be vacant. You could look into hiring a property management company to stop by periodically, and to take care of any problems that popup. You don't want to miss a notice from the HOA and have even more headaches.
Understand the warranty information from the builder. They will sometimes schedule a revisit a few months later to take care of any warranty issues that take time to surface.
Vacant houses can be targeted. Never having signs of life could be a concern.


Is there anything wrong with me buying the new home and then moving in 60 days later?

Financially
If you can afford it then that's your prerogative ¯\(ツ)/¯
Legally
Check with your HOA if you have one.
Check with your town about vacant property rules.
Structurally
If a water pipe bursts then how long before you detect the damage?
Unplanned
A squatter moves in.
A thief steals all your copper or appliances.
Someone throws rocks through all your windows.
